# PHP using XAMPP Displaying BLOB img as an image not Binary code

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp, backend

I am trying to echo the database with PHP to show my entire table including the images, but all I'm getting when it comes to the images is the binary code. Please help:

PHP

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>connecting to a Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        $db = mysql_select_db('dinnerpartydata');

      if($con){
          echo 'Successfully connected to the database.';
      }else {
          die('Error.');
      }
      if($db){
          echo 'Successfully found the database';
      }else {
          die('Error. database not found.');
      }
      ?>
<br />
<br />
      <?php 
        $query= mysql_query("SELECT * from recipesnimages");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $recipeType = $row['recipeType'];
            $recipeName = $row['recipeName'];
            $Instructions = $row['Instructions'];
            $recipeImg = $row['recipeImg'];

            echo $id . '| ' . $recipeType . '| ' . $recipeName . '| ' . $Instructions .'| ' . $recipeImg .'<br />';

        }
      ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably need to convert and put it as an image into the webpage you are printing: echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $recipeImg ).'"/>'. Depending, of course, on the exact formats you are using.

Comment: Hey kiteflight, I am using jpgs that are all 150X150. I am having trouble understanding how this conversion works. could you please reply an example with my code in mind?

Comment: Try changing your code like this (will work only if the image is saved in the db using base64 encoding, otherwise you'll have to adapt to your format used): echo $id . '| ' . $recipeType . '| ' . $recipeName . '| ' . $Instructions .'| ' . <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $recipeImg ).'"/> .'<br />';

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for this query if anyone is intrested:

> connecting to a Database
>
> ```
>   if($con){
>       echo 'Successfully connected to the database.';
>   }else {
>       die('Error.');
>   }
>   if($db){
>       echo 'Successfully found the database';
>   }else {
>       die('Error. database not found.');
>   }
>   ?> <br /> <br />
>   <?php 
>     $query= mysql_query("SELECT * from recipesnimages");
>     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
>         $id = $row['id'];
>         $recipeType = $row['recipeType'];
>         $recipeName = $row['recipeName'];
>         $Instructions = $row['Instructions'];
>         $recipeImg = $row['recipeImg'];
>
>         echo $id . '| ' . $recipeType . '| ' . $recipeName . '| ' . $Instructions .'| '. '<img
> ```
>
> src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($recipeImg).'"
>   height="150" width="200"/>';
>               echo '
> ';
>
> ```
>     }
>   ?>
>
> </body> </html>
> ```